# Making shader takes vertexArray as canvas instead of the window

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, sfml

Currently developing an open source GUI SFML based library, but struggling a bit with shaders. So far I've managed to render shader with no problem, but instead of applying the shader on the current object, it's apply it for the whole window, but only visible in the object range.

Here's my simple code:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include <iostream>

const char *glsl = R"(
    #version 330 core
    uniform vec2 u_resolution;

    void main() {
        vec2 pos = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution;
        float radius = 0.4;
        float d = distance(pos, vec2(0.5));

        gl_FragColor = d <= radius ? vec4(pos.y,pos.y/2.,pos.y, 1.0) : vec4(d*0.8, d*0.8, d*0.8, 1.0);


        //gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0);
    }
)";

const char *pos = R"(
    // some default shader I've found
    // adding #version 330 core will complain for outdated gl_Position variable..

    void main() {
        gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;

        gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
    }
)";

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "GLSL", sf::Style::Default);

    // create a quad
    sf::VertexArray quad(sf::Quads, 4);
    // define it as a rectangle, located at (10, 10) and with size 100x100
    quad[0].position = sf::Vector2f(100, 100);
    quad[1].position = sf::Vector2f(410, 100);
    quad[2].position = sf::Vector2f(410, 410);
    quad[3].position = sf::Vector2f(100, 410);


    sf::Shader shader;
    // the following line is the same as shader.loadFromMemory(pos, glsl);
    shader.loadFromMemory(glsl, sf::Shader::Fragment);
    shader.setUniform("u_resolution", sf::Vector2f(800, 600));

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color(244,244,244));

        window.draw(quad, &shader);

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Not sure what do to for now, but I guess that `pos` shader should affect how the rendering is done. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just some minor changes needed. I'm not exactly sure what's the best way to get it done in any more modern shader version, but if you omit any version markers (i.e. using legacy code), it's quick to change:

First of all, your individual vertices (or more specific the rendered fragments) don't know where they are relative to the quad being drawn. Luckily you can abuse texture coordinates for this. For example, define the top left as `(0, 0)` and the bottom right as `(1, 1)`. This way their values will range from 0 to 1 based on where the fragment is. This is basically what your existing shader code calculates as `pos`.

So let's start by adding the texture coordinates:

```
quad[0].position = sf::Vector2f(100, 100);
quad[0].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(0, 0);
quad[1].position = sf::Vector2f(410, 100);
quad[1].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(1, 0);
quad[2].position = sf::Vector2f(410, 410);
quad[2].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(1, 1);
quad[3].position = sf::Vector2f(100, 410);
quad[3].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(0, 1);
```

Now all we have to do is assign the texture coordinates to `pos` (or better remove `pos completely`). For simplification I'll just go with the assignment:

```
vec2 pos = gl_TexCoord[0].xy;
```

However, this will cause the shader compiler to complain, since `gl_TexCoord` got removed. So for testing I just removed the precompiler line and the result looks like what you've had in mind I guess:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Seems to do the job, but seems a little bit hardcoded. I'll take this as an answer if I won't get anything better, thanks a lot !

Comment: Actually setting the quad textCoords

Comment: @RazvanAlex Think you're misunderstanding this. You only have to set them once and can keep them as they are. You just have to adjust the vertex coordinates as you did before. The texture coordinates default to `(0, 0)`. I basically only changed the default values.

Comment: Sounds good, but since I'm developing a library, would be actually pretty nice to use modern aproches compatible with #version 330 or more, but your answer is still valid unless I get something more "modern" ;)

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely possible to do with newer versions. One just has to find out how. :D