# Using only the sprite to draw

Tags: c++, 2d, shader, sprite, sfml

New to game development with SFML and really like it.

So far I'm trying to render a circle on a sprite, but somehow I only get a quarter of the circle meaning that the window is taken as surface when drawing instead of sprite. If I make the sprie size as the window, I'll see the full circle..

Here's my code:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

const char *glsl = R"(
    #version 330 core
    uniform vec2 u_resolution;

    void main() {
        vec2 pos = gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution;

        float radius = 0.4;
        float d = smoothstep(radius + 0.01, radius, distance(pos, vec2(0.5)));

        gl_FragColor = vec4(d*0.0, d*0.5, d*1.0, 1.0);
    }
)";

int main() {
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "GLSL", sf::Style::Default);

    sf::Texture tex;
    tex.create(800 / 2, 600 /2); // or tex.create(800, 600); for full window surface
    sf::Sprite spr(tex);

    sf::Shader shader;
    shader.loadFromMemory(glsl, sf::Shader::Fragment);
    shader.setUniform("u_resolution", sf::Vector2f(800, 600));

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed) window.close();

        window.clear(sf::Color(244,244,244));

        window.draw(spr, &shader);
        window.display();
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciate. What I'm looking to achieve is to render the full circle in the sprite range. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SFML/GLSL - Making shader takes vertexArray as canvas instead of the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47702694/sfml-glsl-making-shader-takes-vertexarray-as-canvas-instead-of-the-window)

Comment: Is this some kind of classroom task or are you reposting the almost exact same question under different usernames?

Comment: I've seen that one, but seem a little outdated..and yes, it's a task...

Comment: Okay, so overall question is what you want. If the circle should fill the window, just upscale the sprite (see Rodolphe's answer below). If you want to scale the circle to the sprite, check the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

You take a quarter of the screen because you do `tex.create(800 / 2, 600 /2);` and your window size is `sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600) ...);`. So it devide by the width and the height. Create a texture with the same size that your window and I think you'll be good (`tex.create(800, 600);`).

Comment: Yeah I know, but I'm looking to apply the shader for the sprite, not for the whole window. Aka, finally, the circle should be rendered in a portion of the window, not on the whole window..

Comment: Okay, so change your `shader.setUniform("u_resolution", sf::Vector2f(800, 600));` into `shader.setUniform("u_resolution", sf::Vector2f(tex.getSize()));`

Comment: Seems to be something else, I'm getting the circle in the left-bottom quart of the screen it seems, I'll see if I can modify the values somehow to get it where I want

Comment: Where is the center of your circle on the render ? (bottom left or center ?)